# Language translation in an array

Tags: android, internationalization

I have a few arrays and one goes with a spinner but I doubt that matters.

Anyways I need to translate those to other languages. My program is an android app and I have used the @string for most of the app but the arrays are kicking my arse.

Here is the spinner array.

```
    private static final String[]paths = {"Click to select", "One", "Two", "Three"};
```

How on earth do I translate the text in the array? I have tried several ways on other sites and all of them failed to even build.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this finally.

String.xml

```
    <string-array name="paths_array">
         <item>Click to select</item>
         <item>One</item>
         <item>Two</item>
         <item>Three</item>
    </string-array>
```

In the code(java file)

```
    String[] paths;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

    paths = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.paths_array);
    }
```

Super simple and I found it on the Android resource site from Google LOL I thought I had tried it once but after looking at the XML entries I realised it was completely different from what I tried before.

Now compiling and running perfectly and can finally translate the spinner.

Thanks for all the help as it lead me down the right path.

Comment: You could put all the separate strings in in the strings.xml file and reference them in your array. E.g. <string name="one">One</string> and then in the array: <item>@string/one</item>

Answer (score 0):

Just resolve the strings at runtime, and put those resolved strings into the array.

```
String s1 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.s1);
String s2 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.s2);
String s3 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.s3);
String s4 = context.getResources().getString(R.string.s4);

String[] paths = { s1, s2, s3, s4 };
```

And in your string resource file:

```
 <string name="s1">Click to select</string>
 <string name="s2">One</string>
 <string name="s3">Two</string>
 <string name="s4">Three</string>
```

Comment: Never came accross this.... Will give it a try and see what happens. Lots of cutting and pasting going to happening lol

Comment: This doesn't work. Constantly complains about the id1,2,3,4. Says "cannot resolve symble id1"

Comment: I have corrected the answer.  I had mis-typed the string ID.  I put "R.string.id1", but it should have been "R.string.s1", etc.

Comment: Made those changes and the app crashes. If I revert back to the regular array no crash.

Comment: Do you have the logcat output of the crash?